# Help identifying (or finding similar) fonts

Tags: fonts, typography, font-identification

I'd like to see if I can find a free font(s) similar to the font(s) listed below. I think the originals were probably hand painted, but I have no doubt that there are free fonts out there that are similar. Any thoughts?

Ideally, I'd like one font that is similar to "The Adventures OF" and one font that it is similar to "Robin Hood."

If either of them is a web font, that would be even better =).

[image]

EDIT ADD
another picture with the letter from the same movie -

[image]

Comment: Search: 'gothic fonts'.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know what these types of fonts were called.

Comment: You can also search for "blackletter", since "gothic", although one of the other names for this style, is used as well for a completely different font family.

Comment: Blackletter is definitely the common term that will likely lead you to plenty of options.

Comment: Gothic, Gothic script, Gothic minuscule, Fraktur, Textura and Old English are Blackletter 'sub categories'. Grotesque, Grotesk, English Egyptian or Gothic (again!) are the sans serif typefaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adventure is close (not identical) to [Amador](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/parkinson/amador/regular/glyphs.html) -

[image]

[image]

If you want to find free font, try to look for fonts SIMILAR : **LTC Goudy Text**, Monotype **Goudy Text**, **Octoberfest**, **Cabazon**, Engravers' **Old English**, **Gothique**, Old English (these are not free)

Comment: Those aren't all free fonts. LTC Goudy and Monotype Goudy, for example, are both commercial typefaces.

Comment: @yes, I meant similar fonts. Will correct